How to use multiple middleware to a laravel route group?
I'm trying to add a new middleware to a group of routes that I got in my routes/web.php
Route::group(['middleware'=>['xFrameOptionsHeader','VerifyHeaders']], function(){
    Route::get('/', 'PagesController@getIndex');
    Route::get('/otherroute', 'PagesController@getOtherRoute'); // etc...
});

The code was working when I had only the xFrameOptionsHeader middleware, then I used the command
php artisan make:middleware VerifyHeaders

which at the moment looks like this only:
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class VerifyHeaders
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response)  $next
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
        return $next($request);
    }
}

But when I navigate to / the app fails with the error message:
 Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
Target class [VerifyHeaders] does not exist.

Also I didn't find in the docs the correct way to add multiple middleware by Route::group, so what am I missing here? Also tried the solutions from this question but also the same error.

Well I just found out what I was missing
Since this Laravel project was crated long time ago (I think that was in Laravel 6), the way to define new Middleware was by adding them to the app/Http/Kernel.php class as described in the old docs here. Although I updated to Laravel 11 following the instructions on their site this error still happened...

Laravel 11 doesn't use simple strings to register middleware like Laravel 6 did. Instead, you would add a use App\Http\Middleware\VerifyHeaders; statement at the top of your routes/web.php file, and then in your Middleware group use the following syntax to import the FQN of your middleware class: VerifyHeaders::class
